# How to get Window or Form handle in IronPython to pass to C# code

Tags: .net, windows, camera, ironpython

I am attempting to use an IDS uEye USB camera from IronPython and the .net API provided by IDS. I appear to be finding and initializing the camera and getting a live video stream. The problem is in displaying the images. The IDS net api requires a handle (intptr?) to the window. I have created an IronPython form (System.Windows.Forms.Form) which is defined to be an IronPython.NewTypes.System.Windows.Form.Form_4$4 (what ever that is!). However, I have not been able to figure out how to get the handle to that form. If I simply use:

`Class MyForm(Form):
     def **init**(self)
       self.height = 200
       self.width  = 200

and create the form as:

```
`displayForm = MyForm()
```

I would have thought that the variable form was in fact the pointer or handle to the GUI structure. It appears to not be so, as when I attempt to pass it to the uEye api, as

```
`cam.Display.Render(memID, displayForm, s32Mode)
```

where memID and s32Mode are simply integer values I get the error:

```
`Type Error: expected IntPtr got Form_4$4
```

I tried:

```
`DisplayHandle = clr.Reference[IntPtr](displayForm)
```

and this gave me the error for the same error:

I'm lost. I've Googled everything I can think of and have not found an answer. Can someone please help me out so I can get the video from this camera displayed!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the Form's [Handle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.handle.aspx) property. This is the Windows handle (HWND).

```
displayForm.Handle
```